# How to click a button on MS Access with Python

Tags: python, ms-access, win32com

i'm trying to automate some data extraction from a MS Access database (.accdb) query.

I'm using win32com to open the Access Database and i retrieved all the informations About the widgets i want to interact with. I can modify widget values and open forms, read and create queries, although i don't know how to click a button (CommandButton).

My code is simple and it's something like this:

```
import win32com.client as win

access = win.Dispatch('Access.Application')
access.Visible = True
db = access.OpenCurrentDatabase(r'databasepath.accdb')
app.DoCmd.OpenForms(formname)
```

and then i can reference all the widget i want to interact with through:

```
widget = app.Forms(formname).Controls(widgetname)
```

How can i click a CommandButton after i referenced it? I checked MS Access documentation for Command Object but there's not a click method. The workaround i'm using is:

```
widget.SetFocus()
shell.SendKeys('{Enter}') #it refers to WScript.Shells
```

But i don't want to use SendKeys because it can easily generate an error, for instance if the user is working on something else. I also considered to read the SQL query that is involved behind the button click in order to study another workaround, although i leave it as last option.

Answer (score 2):

Simply call the trigger event as if a property of form. However, be sure in MS Access the button is defined as `Public` and not `Private` as in: `Public Sub myButton_Click()`.  And of course with any API integration, be sure to wrap in `try/except` for clean release of resources, error or not:

```
import win32com.client as win

try:
    access = win.Dispatch('Access.Application')
    db = access.OpenCurrentDatabase(r'C:\Full\Path\To\myDatabase.accdb')
    access.DoCmd.OpenForms(formname)

    # RUN BUTTON CLICK EVENT (OPEN PARENTHESES REQUIRED)
    access.Forms(formname).myButton_Click()

    access.Visible = True

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    access.DoCmd.CloseDatabase()
    access.Quit()

finally:
    db = None; access = None
    del db; del access
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately its defined as Private and not Public.

Comment: If you cannot change it, then above method will not work. Only the functions defined in the scope of your Access form can run the button click event with `Private`. All external processing like Python even other Access modules cannot call it.